# How to change google translator selectbox to normal links listing?

Tags: transliteration

I want to change google translator display layout from select box list to normal  links list.I'm using below code.  For more info http://screencast.com/t/3MPGGygRkX . Please help.

```
<div id="google_translate_element">
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',includedLanguages: 'en,es', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script></div>
```